# Assistance with query logic needed

Tags: sql, join, temp-tables

I will try to keep this as simple as possible.  I have tried a few ways but always have gotten stuck.  So my question is, what would be the best route of gathering the following data?

Logic:
If provider and carrier is Status LP,CP,PP in Region 'CI' then the same provider and carrier should be status 'OP' in Region 'UI'.

The above logic will use the same table. This is an error report.  Therefore, I need to show errors where the provider/carrier combination is not 'OP' in Region 'UI' when they have LP,CP,PP in Region 'CI'. They do not NEED an 'OP' record if they have they the combo in 'CI'.  However, if they do have the record in 'CI' then I need to check to see if they have a record in 'UI'.  If they do, it must be Status 'OP'.

Here is the query I used based on your logic.  I am not sure if this is correct as I haven't ran test queries.

```
Select distinct aff.aff_no, aff.prov_no, IRS_No,prog_no, Last_name,     First_name + ' ' + Last_name as Provider_Name, prov.CONTROL_NO, office_no, aff.Carrier, aff.[Region], aff.pay_class, aff.status, aff.spec_1, aff.op_no, aff.hat_code, aff.area, aff.period_table_no, pat_to as pay_to, aff.medicare_no, aff. eff_date, aff.end_date, aff.trans_date, 'Status/Region Error' As [Rept Error], ACTIVE_PATIENTS as member_cnt
from  amisys.dbo.Provider Prov  

INNER JOIN amisys.dbo.Affiliation Aff
on Prov.Prov_no = Aff.Prov_No
where aff.end_date = '12/31/9999'
and aff.void = ' '
and PAY_CLASS <> 'dummy'
and irs_no = '721269878'
and status in ('PP','LP','CP')
and region = 'CI'
and HAT_CODE = 'SP'
and EXISTS(Select 1 from amisys.dbo.Affiliation aff2
       Where aff.prov_no = aff2.PROV_NO
          and aff.carrier = aff2.carrier
          and aff2.region = 'UI'
          and aff2.status = 'OP')
```

Can someone please help me complete this if I am on the right track?  If not, can someone please show me how this should be coded?

Thanks a bunch,
Greg

Comment: A good place to start is with sample data and desired results (both for a question on the web and for working on it yourself).  I understand the logic, but have no idea what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, and you want to get all the members_no that has both (country='A',status ='CI') and (country = 'B',status = 'OP') then you don't need to use a temp table at all, it can be done in a lot of ways, one of them is EXISTS:

```
SELECT m.member_No, m.Code_No, m.Status, m.County, m.City, m.State, m.Zip
FROM dbo.member m
WHERE m.county = 'B' and
      m.Status = 'OP' and
      EXISTS(select 1 from dbo.member m2
             where m.member_no = m2.member_no
                and m.code_no = m2.code_no
                and m2.country = 'A'
                and m2.status = 'CI')
```

You can also use join:

```
    SELECT m.member_No, m.Code_No, m.Status, m.County, m.City, m.State, m.Zip
    FROM dbo.member m
    INNER JOIN dbo.member m2
     ON(m.member_no = m2.member_no and m.code_no = m2.code_no
        and m.country = 'B' and m.status = 'OP'
        and m2.country = 'A' and m2.status = 'CI')
```

Comment: This is a great start!  I may have no included some information, for this I apologize.  This is basically an 'error' capturing query.  I need to find where there is member_no and code_no combination of Status PP,LP,CP in county A but there is not a member_no/code_no combination of Status OP in county B.  I know everyone is probably confused right now because I wrote this terribly.  Let me try to do this again with using more accurate data (as opposed to fake data with same logic).

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this data when you get a chance?  I have updated the logic and everything as well.  My fake data interpreted as this:

member_no = provider_no
code_no = carrier
county = region

Comment: @GregoryBrauninger The query you posted looks good, try to run it and tell me if it works

Comment: The query ran perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help.  I did run into one problem before the previous edit.  I didn't have the (aff.) alias in the exists statement which returned incorrect results.  After adding it, it looks perfect.  I ran test queries and everything is checking out.  I have been working on this for a while.  You sir, are a wizard.